# JSR305 OSGi Exports brave

Tags: java, osgi, zipkin, jsr305

The brave core module has added exports for javax.annotation;version="[3.0.0,4)", this causing issue when deploying OSGi applications using brave in JBoss Fuse - as the System bundle already exports javax.annotation;version="1.0".

Wondering why devtime dependencies like findbugs(JSR305) packages be exported as part of runtime ??

Any workaround for this ?? Can we not sue JSR 305 bundles from servicemix to make brave OSGi bundles compliant with common containers like karaf et al??

Comment: Details of it is available here https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/451

Comment: Can you describe the steps to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The google's findbugs JSR305 dependency was exporting javax.annotation;version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)" which was causing the issue as mentioned in the issue using service mix JSR305 bundles properly exports the javax.annotation;version="[1.1,2)"